# Virtual network terminology: is a NATed or routed bridge an oxymoron?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, virtual-machine, bridge

According to p. 166 of *Mastering KVM Virtualization* by Chirammal et al (Packt, 2016), the "Virtual Networks" tab in [Virt-Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Virtual_Machine_Manager&oldid=781011620) allows the creation of three kinds of virtual networks:

- NATed
- Routed
- Isolated

Looking at the network creation dialogue linked to that tab, this seems to be broadly true.

Having allowed Virt-Manager to create, by default, a NATed virtual network on a PC running [Debian 9 "Stretch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Debian_version_history&oldid=807068891#Debian_9_.28Stretch.29), I see that `sudo brctl show` yields (bridge ID modified for privacy):

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.5254009dcac5   yes     virbr0-nic
```

This raises questions, e.g.:

- If `virbr0` is a [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bridging_(networking)&oldid=796603889), then how can it also function as a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Network_address_translation&oldid=809194179#One-to-many_NAT)?
- Is `virbr0` the only thing that Virt-Manager created when I allowed it to make a virtual network, or did it create something else (e.g. a virtual NAT router, to which `virbr0` was connected)?
- *Additional question:* Assuming that the host has one physical (Ethernet) NIC connected to a LAN, and that two guest virtual machines, VM1 and VM2, are connected to `virbr0`, what does the network topology look like?

#### Addendum

Here are the iptables and ebtables states, as mentioned in the comment and answers so far:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

$ sudo iptables -t nat -vL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1556 packets, 130K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 726 packets, 82025 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15148 packets, 953K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 15148 packets, 953K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   84 11805 RETURN     all  --  any    any     192.168.122.0/24     base-address.mcast.net/24 
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
  267 16020 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  any    any     192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
  206 15656 MASQUERADE  udp  --  any    any     192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    1    84 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    any     192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    


$ sudo ebtables -L
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT
```

Comment: Not familiar with what Virt-Manager does, but the obvious first place to look is `ebtables` and/or `iptables`. Also, if it uses `macvlan`s, they come in several modes, e.g. `private` for isolation.

Comment: There needs to be a bridge created first so as to allow the virtual hosts created to communicate with the physical network interface.  The NAT is on the other side of the bridge.

Comment: @dirkt, thanks. I have added `iptables -L` and `ebtables -L` output. Is there any other command output that you think would be useful for answering this question, e.g. w.r.t. `macvlan`s?

Comment: @RubberStamp, not sure I understand you, sorry :( The PC's physical network interface is already connected to a LAN. Are you saying that a single physical network interface can be connected to two network segments at once?

Comment: The host system needs to propagate the network to the virtual systems.  This is done via a host bridge which is probably what you are referring to as `virbr0` ...  The virtual hosts have their own interfaces which connect to your physical host's network interface through the bridge.  The NAT is within the virtual host, not the physical host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If `virbr0` is a bridge, then how can it also function as a NAT?

Well, it doesn't. But the system itself has a port in the bridge, and if there's an IP address set on the bridge, then it can do routing/forwarding/NAT between the bridge and some other interface.

So, assuming you have, say `eth0` as the uplink and `virbr0` bridging the VMs, which show up as `vmnic0` and so on. Then you'd have something like this:

```
      ^
      |
    eth0 (192.0.2.111 - your external IP)
      |
[[ routing / NAT ]]
      |
   virbr0 (10.0.1.1 - this system on the VM bridge)
      |
   +--+-----+-----+-------+       (the bridging part)
   |        | ... |       |
  vmnic0               vmnicN
```

Here, `eth0` is not part of the bridge. If it were, the VMs would be bridged to the external network without routing. (The `vmnic`s might be named in some other fashion, I can't remember the naming conventions used...)

`ifconfig` or `ip addr` should be able to show you the bridge IP, and you need `iptables -t nat -vL` to see the iptables NAT rules.

---

Now, the `virbr0-nic` in your example is apparently a dummy device created to give the bridge an unchanging MAC address. According to [an explanation in the `libvirt-users` mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2012-September/msg00038.html):

> It's a workaround for kernel bug/feature. The bridge's MAC is copied
>   from the first NIC attached. So if one detach all interfaces from a
>   bridge and then attach just one, the bridge will lost previous MAC and
>   gain a new one - just the same as the attached interface has.
>
> So if libvirt has to ensure a MAC for virtual bridge - it creates this
>   dummy device (no traffic is routed through though) and just attach it
>   to the virtual bridge.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful :) The "routing / NAT" part of your diagram: is that being handled by the iptables rules in the addendum to my question, or do I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: BTW, where would `virbr0-nic` fit in to this diagram? (P.S. It might be helpful if you use `virbr0` instead of `br0`, to match my question and reduce confusion.) And for clarity, can I confirm that the IP addresses you've chosen for your diagram (192.0.2.111 and 10.0.1.1) are just plausible ones from within the [private IPv4 address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces), and are not magical in any way? Thanks again :)

Comment: I've tentatively marked this answer as correct. If @ilkkachu or anyone else finds time, do please edit it to more fully answer my questions above. Thanks.

Comment: @sampablokuper, I first thought `virbr0-nic` was a NIC of a VM, but the naming seemed odd, as usually the VM NICs would have some index number (since it would be too useful to give them meaningful names). But apparently it's a sort of a placeholder for the bridge MAC address. 192.0.2.0/24 is a "reserved for documentation and examples" block, and 10.0.0.0/8 of course is one of the RFC1918 local-use/private network blocks. ([Wikipedia has a nice list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses))

Comment: Thanks :) Incidentally, I can confirm that the rules in the NAT table disappear when I stop the virtual network using virt-manager. So, it's clear that virt-manager created the latter, as well as the bridge. This answers the second bullet point in my original question.

Comment: @sampablokuper, yeah, that was expected. And `ifconfig` or such would have probably have shown you `virbr0` has an address in the `192.168.122.0/24` block that was mentioned in the iptables rules. (If I were build such a configuration, I'd make the iptables rules work by _interface_, not the IP address block. Apparently libvirt has a different view on this, though of course it doesn't matter as long as the address configurations match.)